# Rigid body collision... normals?

Tags: java, geometry, physics, collision

So, I've been learning physics, calculus, geometry, etc. I'm working on a test of collision, normals and such. So, I more or less know the math behind the collision itself, but what about getting the normal? I have two center of masses, and a point of impact, I can subtract shape 2's position from shape 1's position to get the hit vector, but how do I get a normal? 90 degree rounding and such wouldn't work, as I'm using rotation for my shapes(although working with torque and angular momentum is later on). I've tried googling my question, but all I can find is how to detect/handle collisions(with the normals precalculated, or not making any sense).

Comment: Question is way too broad. Please provide more information.  And some code.

Comment: This question is off-topic because OP has not made any effort to make this a programming, rather than mathematical, question.

Answer (score 2):

If your collision is between rigid bodies, then the "normal" is the vector perpendicular to the surface at the point of impact. For spheres this is the radial vector (vector between centers); for other shapes you have to draw a diagram to see which way the normal is pointing. At any rate the normals of the two will by the definition of the point of collision have to be equal but opposite (see Newton's laws for a refresher of why that must be).

Comment: Wait, so how would I do this in a programmatic environment? I've got velocity, position, and the vector from the center of mass from the first to the second. I still don't understand how you would calculate this, for say a rotated square. I do see how you would for a circle though.

Comment: Be more specific about the geometry, and draw a picture. There is no "general" answer - although if one of the bodies is a sphere and you know the point of collision, then the direction of the normal is trivially the vector from the center of the sphere to the point of collision. And if one square's corner hits the face of another square, the normal is the normal to the face that was hit.

Comment: It would be a polygon, as my circle/squares are just turned into polygons to allow manipulation and inter-shape collision detection. Is there any working method for polygons?

Comment: You will always (?) have "corner of one hits face of the other". The normal to the face is the one you are after. If you can't figure out what the normal to an edge of a polygon is, I can't help you...

Comment: But what if two corners or two faces collide? I guess if two corners collided, they objects would slide past each other, but what about 2 faces? Besides that, yes, you told me what I needed to know, thanks!

Comment: If the two faces collide, their normals will be the same. If the corners collide, then the normal will be parallel to the line connecting the centers of mass. But in principle the probability of that happening is infinitesimally small...